# Logstash is not creating index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-10, logstash, kibana

It doesn't show any error on console. Here is the command I'm running ( On Windows 10. ) -

```
logstash --verbose -f logstash-sample.conf
```

Here is my `logstash-sample.conf` file -

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\17739\Documents\IIT\CSP586\tutorial\project\ChicagoSocialHub\backend-build-divvy-status\divvy_stations_status.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
   csv{
      separator => ","
      columns => ["altitude", "availableBikes", "availableDocks", "city", "id", "is_renting", "kioskType", "landMark", "lastCommunicationTime", "latitude", "location", "longitude", "postalCode", "stAddress1", "stAddress2", "stationName", "status", "statusKey", "statusValue", "testStation", "totalDocks"]
      }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "divvy_stations_status"
  document_type => "status"
   }
  stdout {
  codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

And here is the logstash console output -

```
C:\Users\17739\Documents\IIT\CSP586\logstash-6.6.2\bin>logstash --verbose -f logstash-sample.conf
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Users/17739/Documents/IIT/CSP586/logstash-6.6.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-03-17T12:56:36,728][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-03-17T12:56:36,745][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.6.2"}
[2019-03-17T12:56:41,603][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch index=>"divvy_stations_status", id=>"f84c43181aab6f7bf9e89c0412ada5b5ead116534f6661194800152751a28e87", hosts=>[//localhost:9200], document_type=>"status", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_1264be19-323c-4896-8214-929f15a74251", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, manage_template=>true, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>false, ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing=>false, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,234][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,548][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,695][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,735][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,739][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,768][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,782][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2019-03-17T12:56:43,801][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2019-03-17T12:56:44,323][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"C:/Users/17739/Documents/IIT/CSP586/logstash-6.6.2/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_6f34c293ff88e0ad3c31e4a0f32e43d9", :path=>["C:\\Users\\17739\\Documents\\IIT\\CSP586\\tutorial\\project\\ChicagoSocialHub\\backend-build-divvy-status\\divvy_stations_status.csv"]}
[2019-03-17T12:56:44,369][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2e991954 run>"}
[2019-03-17T12:56:44,440][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2019-03-17T12:56:44,441][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-03-17T12:56:44,786][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

After running `logstash --verbose -f logstash-sample.conf` command , My expectation is this new index `divvy_stations_status` will be visible in elastic search indices(checked with kibana as well , not showing up there as well) . Is that a true expectation ? Here is my 
output -

[image]

Comment: Did you get any output in the console since you have the `stdout` enabled? Also, have you tried to use a forward slash (`/`) in your path configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was giving `forward slash` `/` instead of `backward slash` `\` in the file path. This was weird, since in windows we always use a forward slash for a path separator. And what more weird was it never threw an error like 'File not found or something'

So in `logstash-sample.conf` file use the following -

```
path => "C:/Users/17739/Documents/IIT/CSP586/tutorial/project/ChicagoSocialHub/backend-build-divvy-status/divvy_stations_status.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

@sapy ,

When You are trying to run logstash in Windows platform,

You have to change the filepath as

`C:/Users/17739/Documents/IIT/CSP586/tutorial/project/ChicagoSocialHub/backend-build-divvy-status/divvy_stations_status.csv`

ie,use **forward slash** in the place of backward slash.
and second

you need to specify the

`sincedb_path => "NUL"`

in input plugin

It keeps track of the current position of monitored log files.

These two are good practice when developing logstash conf files.