# Logstash starting but not creating indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am trying to create an index in elasticsearch using a csv file. Below is the configuration.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\soumdash\Desktop\Accounts.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
  }
}

filter {
  csv{
     separator => ","
     columns => ["Country_code","Account_number","User_ID","Date","Time"]
  }
  mutate {convert => ["Account_number","integer"]}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "accounts"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

I am starting the logstash and from the console I can see that it has bee started and the pipeline has been created. But I cannot see the same index in kibana.

```
C:\Users\soumdash\Desktop\logstash-7.2.0\bin>logstash -f logstash-account.conf
Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Users/soumdash/Desktop/logstash-7.2.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-07-26T14:01:27,662][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-07-26T14:01:27,711][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.2.0"}
[2019-07-26T14:01:42,181][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch index=>"accounts", id=>"b54e1c07198cf188279cb051e01c9fe6118db48fe2ce76739dc2ace82e02c078", hosts=>[//localhost:9200], document_type=>"ERC_Acoounts", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_57f41853-7ddf-48e5-a5e4-316d94c83a0f", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, manage_template=>true, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>"auto", ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing=>false, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
[2019-07-26T14:01:46,248][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2019-07-26T14:01:46,752][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2019-07-26T14:01:46,852][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2019-07-26T14:01:46,862][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2019-07-26T14:01:46,910][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2019-07-26T14:01:47,046][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using default mapping template
[2019-07-26T14:01:47,205][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2019-07-26T14:01:47,236][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been create for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2019-07-26T14:01:47,236][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x26c630b8 run>"}
[2019-07-26T14:01:52,105][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2019-07-26T14:01:52,232][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-07-26T14:01:52,249][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2019-07-26T14:01:53,290][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

I have checked and tried a few other answers on the same issue such as 
[Logstash creates pipeline but index is not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299360/logstash-creates-pipeline-but-index-is-not-created) and 
[Logstash is not creating index in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210303/logstash-is-not-creating-index-in-elastic-search)
But with no success result.

Can anyone please help? I am using ELK 7.2.

Comment: I can't see any output due to `stdout {}` in the logs as well. Is your file being read?

Comment: How can I confirm that? Sorry I am new to ELK. I have added rubydebug with a file for the output.

`output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 index => "accounts"
  }
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\soumdash\Desktop\temp"
 codec => rubydebug
  }
}`

But still the same

Comment: Hi did you figure it out? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you use rubydebug inside of stdout,just to make sure that you file is read?

Comment: I have added it .Even tried to output into a file.

`output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 index => "accounts"
  }
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\soumdash\Desktop\temp"
 codec => rubydebug
  }
}`

but no change

Comment: Can you remove ```sincedb_path``` option, and try again?

Comment: It's still the same after deleting sincedb_path

Comment: For the path in input part, you need to replace ```back slash \ ``` with ```forward slash /```

Comment: And return back `sincedb_path => "NUL"`